# Unibranch rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let us call a Noetherian local ring $A$ unibranch if it is a domain and the normalization map is finite and induces a bijection on spectra.

My question is as follows: is this property preserved when one completes at the maximal ideal of $A$? What about being geometrically unibranch?

Comment: If the completion is a domain, then it's unibranch.  An exercise in Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra: http://books.google.com/books?id=Bb30CjGW7EAC&lpg=PA363&ots=BsM4c5G7cR&dq=completion%20unibranch&pg=PA363#v=onepage&q=completion%20unibranch&f=false

Comment: In that exercise "unibranch" means something much weaker: the normalization has only one point over the closed point.

Comment: Isn't this a counterexample? Let $B$ be $\mathbb C[x,y]$ and let $A\subset B$ consist of those $f(x,y)$ such that $f(1-t^2,t-t^3)=f(1-t^2,t^3-t)$. The normalization is $B$. Localize at the origin. 

Comment: As far as I know, the accepted definition of "unibranch" is given above by Tom. References: EGA 0_I 6.5.10 (Springer edition), and Raynaud, LNM 169, chapter IX which implies that $A$ is unibranch iff its henselization is a domain. Whether the completion is then irreducible was an open problem when EGA IV_4 was written (EGA IV, 18.9.6 (ii)) but it is true if $A$ is excellent (18.9.1).

With JT's definition, Tom's example does look like a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Tom's counter-example is instructive.